# Android: how to play mp4 video from URL?

Tags: java, android, xml, video

I'm trying to play video but having no luck so I'm testing with some bare bones code to see what the problem is. The following doesn't work and I'm not really sure why:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.videotest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.videotest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VideoView vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse("http://somewebsite.com/somevideo.mp4");
        vid.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));        
        vid.start();
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the error I am given when running the code:

```
02-18 10:12:44.071: E/MediaPlayer(8357): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://somewebsite.com/somevideo.mp4
```

Comment: You try another URI for mp4 video start.

Comment: Are you sure that the video exists ?

Comment: http://s1133.photobucket.com/albums/m590/Anniebabycupcakez/?action=view&amp; current=1376992942447_242.mp4

Answer (score 14):

Sample code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.videodisplay);
        String link="http://s1133.photobucket.com/albums/m590/Anniebabycupcakez/?action=view&amp; current=1376992942447_242.mp4";
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your Uri in not genuine. Try  this Uri. Check this link http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-play-mp4-video-in-android-using.html

```
Uri vidUri = Uri.parse("http://s1133.photobucket.com/user/Anniebabycupcakez/media/1489553974996_37622.mp4.html");
```

Comment: your code put into try{}catch(Exception e){} block.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are calling vid.start() before the VideoView is in the correct state, try this:

```
vid.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            vid.start();
        }
    });
vid.setVideoURI(videoUri);
```

You can also register a listener with setOnErrorListener() that might give you more info on why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(""http://somewebsite.com/somevideo.mp4"");

}
```

or with VideoView don't forget requestfocus

```
VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://somewebsite.com/somevideo.mp4"));
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.start();
```

Comment: I tried with request focus. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: This example doesn't work on the emulator. You should use the real mobile phone

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
            + R.raw.abc);
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(this, video);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mp.setDisplay(holder);
    mp.start();
```

or get video from url just pass your url into Uri.parse() method